# Set Accept-Language on PhantomJSDriver in a Play Framework Specification

Tags: scala, selenium, playframework, phantomjs, playframework-2.2

How can the PhantomJSDriver be configured with a specific Accept-Language language header in a Play Framework 2.2 specification?

Given this code:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._
import play.api.i18n._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class IntegrationSpec extends Specification {

  "Application" should {

    "work from within a browser" in new WithBrowser(webDriver = classOf[PhantomJSDriver]) {
      browser.goTo("http://localhost:" + port)
      implicit val lang = Lang("pt-BR")
      val expected = Messages("home.index.featured_lead")
      browser.pageSource must contain(expected)
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make sure that the request generated by `goTO` will be sent with a specific `Accept-Language` header, e.g. `pt-BR`?

**Update:** The objective of the question is to be able to run tests in a simulated browser (such as PhantomJS) with the browser configured for a specific language. The code sample above just asks the browser to detect if there is some localized text in the page, but the kind of tests that can be run in a simulated browser vary a lot. For instance, the text might be set at runtime via JavaScript. Or I may want to take a screenshot and compare it with a previous reference screenshot, to test layouts. By default, apparently the browser is using the machine's locale, which breaks continuous integration tests. So the question is how can PhantomJS be configured from a Play Framework test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [a forum message by Yasuki Okumura](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/vjAhrsD753E/1g4V4saC48AJ), this can be done by creating a `TestBrowser` object from a preconfigured driver.

For example:

In file `WithPhantomJS.scala`:

```
package com.myproject.website.tests

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService
import org.specs2.execute.AsResult
import org.specs2.execute.Result
import org.specs2.mutable.Around
import org.specs2.specification.Scope
import play.api.i18n.Lang
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test.FakeApplication
import play.api.test.TestBrowser
import play.api.test.TestServer
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

abstract class WithPhantomJS(val additionalOptions: Map[String, String] = Map()) extends Around with Scope {

  implicit def app = FakeApplication()

  implicit def port = play.api.test.Helpers.testServerPort

  lazy val browser: TestBrowser = {
    val defaultCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs
    val additionalCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(additionalOptions.asJava)
    val capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(defaultCapabilities, additionalCapabilities)
    val driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities)
    TestBrowser(driver, Some("http://localhost:" + port))
  }

  override def around[T: AsResult](body: => T): Result = {
    try {
      running(TestServer(port, app))(AsResult.effectively(body))
    } finally {
      browser.quit()
    }
  }
}
```

In file `IntegrationSpec.scala`:

```
package com.myproject.website.tests

import com.myproject.common.helpers._
import org.junit.runner._
import org.specs2.runner._
import play.api.i18n._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService

/**
 * An integration test will fire up a whole play application in a real (or headless) browser.
 */
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class IntegrationSpec extends Specification {

  val enUSLangCode = "en-US"
  val ptBRLangCode = "pt-BR"

  val enUSOptions = getPhantomJSLanguageOption(enUSLangCode)
  val ptBROptions = getPhantomJSLanguageOption(ptBRLangCode)

  "Application" should {

    "work from within a browser with en-US language" in new WithPhantomJS(enUSOptions) {
      browser.goTo("http://localhost:" + port)
      implicit val lang = Lang(enUSLangCode)
      val expected = Messages("home.index.featured_lead")
      browser.pageSource must contain(expected)
    }

    "work from within a browser with pt-BR language" in new WithPhantomJS(ptBROptions) {
      browser.goTo("http://localhost:" + port)
      implicit val lang = Lang(ptBRLangCode)
      val expected = Messages("home.index.featured_lead")
      browser.pageSource must contain(expected)
    }

  }

  private def getPhantomJSLanguageOption(langCode: String) =
    Map(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX + "Accept-Language" -> langCode)

}
```

Also, this dependency is required in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.detro.ghostdriver" % "phantomjsdriver" % "1.0.4" % "test"
```

In Play Framework 2.3, the `WithBrowser` class [will accept](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/31afc82125ed75e25d1d1eda9ea9ae132ce98b7e/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Specs.scala#L49) a `WebDriver` instance directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this stopped working for me in after upgrading to play 2.4 (which I assume incidentally upgraded the version of specs2 as well).

Answer (score 0):

According [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141#c11) comment in an issue about reading response headers, it looks like WebDriver does not have an API for setting request headers or checking response headers. The comment suggests using an HTTP client (Play has the [WS Library](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS)) to test request and response headers.

Given that information, you could use the WS Library to check that the server is responding with the language corresponding to the `Accept-Language` header, and any front-end testing you do can assume that the headers are being respected correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The suggested work around isn't enough, though. I'm aware that I can send HTTP requests and get HTTP responses, but this question is about tests running in a simulated browser (in the case, PhantomJS). I'm not trying to retrieve the Accept-Language language header. I'm trying to find out how to configure the simulated browser to run with a specific language. This allows kinds of tests that the WS Library can't do, such as testing JavaScript code that runs on the client, comparing screenshots, etc.

Comment: PhantomJs definitely has the ability to set the Accept-Language header. Could you write your test in javascript to be run by phantomjs directly? You would lose a lot of the functionality that comes with selenium, but you could do all the client side validation that you are looking for. You could even have your scala test just execute the phantomjs executable with the test script.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll keep that in mind if there's no solution using Scala and Play Framework.